# Problema con Ajax vacio!

Tags: php, ajax, zend

Tengo un formulario en el cual hay un textArea. Ese formulario se valida primero por Ajax para comprobar si el texto del texArea es lo suficientemente grande y tras esto, se valida en la acción del controlador par el resto de datos.

Pues bien, la primera vez que hago el submit, el texto del textArea llega vacio y el validador que se hace por ajax da error, pero si vuelvo a hacer le submit sin tocar nada, el texto si que llega bien y se valida todo perfecto.

Codigo en el form que llama a la funcion JS

```
$this->getView()->JQReady('
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
            if (!js.Form.validate($(this), "item/validate")) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();             
            }
        });
    ');
```

Codigo JS

```
validate: function(form, urlValidate) {

    var datastring = form.serialize();
    var returnValue = false;

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: urlValidate,
        data: datastring,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var request = JSON.parse(data);
            if (!request.valid) {
                if (request.exception) {
                    if (request.exception) {
                        form.unbind("submit").submit();
                    }
                    returnValue = true;
                } else {
                    printFormErrors(form, request.errors);
                    restoreSubmitButtonItem();
                }
            } else {

                returnValue = true;
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            form.unbind("submit").submit();
            returnValue = true;
            restoreSubmitButtonItem();
        }
    });

    return returnValue;
}
```

En el controlador solo se hace un isValid.
Alguna idea¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lo personal prefiero hacer las validaciones en php, recuerda que con inspeccionar el codigo fuente de la pagina web pueden editarlo y saltarse cualquier seguridad o limitante de javascript que programes.

De todas formas creo que este codigo en JQUERY te serviria:

Formulario:

```
    <form>
    <p>
        <textarea name="mensaje"></textarea><br>
        <small>Caracteres necesarios: <b id="total">50</b></small>
    </p>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){   

var caracteres_ingresados = 0;
var caracteres_necesarios = 50;

$('textarea[name="mensaje"]').keyup(function(){
    caracteres_necesarios = 50;
    caracteres_ingresados = $(this).val().length;
    caracteres_necesarios = parseInt(caracteres_necesarios) - parseInt(caracteres_ingresados);
    $('#total').html(caracteres_necesarios);
});

$('form').submit(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(caracteres_ingresados >= 50){
        alert("Ok");
        /*
            CODIGO AJAX
        */
    }else{
        alert("Faltan "+caracteres_necesarios+" caracteres por ingresar");
    }
});});
```

Pruebalo y me comentas si te funciona...

Comment: gracias por contestar @stevephp. al final he encontrado el error, es que no lo puse basicamente por que se me pasó pero estaba usando tinymce y no me estaba guardando el texto en el textarea. Solo hay que forzar un save a tinymce para forzar el guardado. Un saludo